# Streaming OpenAI results from a Lambda function using Python

Tags: python, lambda, streaming, openai-api

I'm trying to stream results from Open AI using a Lambda function on AWS using the OpenAI Python library.  For the invoke mode I have: RESPONSE_STREAM.  And, using the example [provided for streaming](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_stream_completions.ipynb), I can see the streamed results in the Function Logs (abbreviated below):

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: 3e0148c3-1269-4e38-bd08-e29de5751f18 Version: $LATEST
{
"choices": [
{
"finish_reason": null,
"index": 0,
"logprobs": null,
"text": "\n"
}
],
"created": 1685755648,
"id": "cmpl-7NALANaR7eLwIMrXTYJVxBpk6tiZb",
"model": "text-davinci-003",
"object": "text_completion"
}
{
"choices": [
{
"finish_reason": null,
"index": 0,
"logprobs": null,
"text": "\n"
}
],....

but, the Response is null.  I've tested this by entering the URL in the browser and by performing a get request via cURL: both respond with null.  Below is the exact code (with the secret key changed) that I used, but it can also be found on the link provided:

```
import json
import openai
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    model_to_use = "text-davinci-003"
    input_prompt="Write a sentence in 4 words."
    
    openai.api_key = 'some-secret key'
    response = openai.Completion.create(
      model=model_to_use,
      prompt=input_prompt,
      temperature=0,
      max_tokens=100,
      top_p=1,
      frequency_penalty=0.0,
      presence_penalty=0.0,
      stream=True
    )
    for chunk in response:
        print(chunk)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having trouble because python runtimes do not currently support streaming responses. From 4/7/2023 [AWS announcement of streaming responses](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-response-streaming/):

> Response streaming currently supports the Node.js 14.x and subsequent managed runtimes.

As of 6/8/2023 this is still true.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [AWS Lambda Web Adapter](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-web-adapter). Here is a [FastAPI Response Streaming example](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-web-adapter/tree/main/examples/fastapi-response-streaming) on AWS Lambda.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34677359)